# Android EGL-ERROR can not start activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, securityexception

I have a problem with I open a new Activity. The app close and does not show any error to the user. I put the code of the activity where I do the call, the activity that should receive the call, the manifest and the log. I debugg the application and the debug does not get to go to the other activity.

```
    //Here I do the call to other activity
    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, RedesActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("redes", redes);
        i.putExtra("token", token);
        i.putExtra("iDUsuario", idUsuario);
        i.putExtra("nombreUsuario", usuario);
        startActivity(i);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        finish();
    }
}


    //The activity that receive the call (RedesActivity)
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Quitamos el encabezado de la app
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    .....
```

The manifiest

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.xxxxxx.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.xxxxxxxx.RedesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_redes" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
    </activity>
```

If I run the app, the application exit and does not show error, but if I degug I can see

```
    08-14 11:23:07.145: E/SurfaceTextureClient(22338):    ISurfaceTexture::setBufferCount(0) returned No such device
    08-14 11:23:07.940: I/Choreographer(22338): Skipped 485 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    08-14 11:23:08.095: E/MaliEGL(22338): void __egl_platform_dequeue_buffer(egl_surface*):1099 [EGL-ERROR] failed to dequeue buffer from native window (0x40de0ad8); err = -19, buf = 0x0
    08-14 11:23:08.100: E/SurfaceTextureClient(22338): ISurfaceTexture::setBufferCount(0) returned No such device
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Show more from crash details

Comment: try to give code properly...its not proper way to ask question.

Comment: Please post proper code. it is confusing

Answer (score 0):

Security Exception occurs when the app does not declare the required Permissions it is using in manifest.

Looks like you are using Internet or reading Wifi states or may be something permission , check your log cat and then add the Uses Permission tag in your manifest like:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUIRED_PERMISSION_HERE" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I have all Internet permission. So, I think that is not the problem

Comment: It could be some other permission too.make sure you have all the required permissions declared in manifest.

Comment: I have this permissions                                                          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: This is ok.nut in your Java Code are you using anything that requires a  permission but you have missed out that.

Comment: Are you not getting any security exception any more!! ?

Comment: When I run mi app, I can not see any exception/error in my log. The application only finish....I don't get to know whats happens...

Comment: so why have you titled your question like that??

Comment: When I degugg de application. I can see that the view is not visible in the line startActivity(i) and the log shows                                                          08-14 12:00:49.165: E/MaliEGL(28179): void __egl_platform_dequeue_buffer(egl_surface*):1099 [EGL-ERROR] failed to dequeue buffer from native window (0x4d4db920); err = -19, buf = 0x0
08-14 12:00:49.170: E/SurfaceTextureClient(28179): ISurfaceTexture::setBufferCount(0) returned No such device
08-14 12:01:01.395: E/SurfaceTextureClient(28179): ISurfaceTexture::setBufferCount(0) returned No such device

Comment: Sorry Nargis. I have changed the title.